# Maven hangs forever when uploading a SECOND package with SAME artifactId

Tags: maven-2, java-6, maven-deploy-plugin, maven-wagon-plugin, wagon

Maven all of a sudden hangs forever at **release:perform** when trying to upload a file:

```
14:49:24 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
14:49:24 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'deploy'.
14:49:25 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:49:25 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] Building dcm4chee - Open Source - Packaging
14:49:25 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO]    task-segment: [deploy:deploy-file] (aggregator-style)
14:49:25 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:49:25 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] [deploy:deploy-file {execution: default-cli}]
14:49:25 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] Uploading: http://mavenrepo:8081/nexus/content/repositories/idc-releases/com/mycompany/impaxdatacenter/dcm4chee-web/3.1.1.0.0-77/dcm4chee-web-3.1.1.0.0-77.war
14:49:25 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] 640K uploaded  (dcm4chee-web-3.1.1.0.0-77.war)
14:49:25 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] Uploading project information for dcm4chee-web 3.1.1.0.0-77
14:49:25 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] Retrieving previous metadata from wtlslmvnp01.aqua.mitra.com
14:49:25 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] Uploading repository metadata for: 'artifact com.mycompany.impaxdatacenter:dcm4chee-web'
14:49:26 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:49:26 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
14:49:26 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:49:26 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] Total time: 1 second
14:49:26 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 14 14:49:26 EDT 2016
14:49:26 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] Final Memory: 10M/111M
14:49:26 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:49:27 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
14:49:27 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'deploy'.
14:49:27 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:49:27 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] Building dcm4chee - Open Source - Packaging
14:49:27 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO]    task-segment: [deploy:deploy-file] (aggregator-style)
14:49:27 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:49:28 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] [deploy:deploy-file {execution: default-cli}]
14:49:28 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] Uploading: http://mavenrepo:8081/nexus/content/repositories/idc-releases/com/mycompany/impaxdatacenter/dcm4chee-web/3.1.1.0.0-77/dcm4chee-web-3.1.1.0.0-77.jar
14:49:28 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] 281K uploaded  (dcm4chee-web-3.1.1.0.0-77.jar)
14:49:28 [INFO] [artifact:mvn] [INFO] Uploading project information for dcm4chee-web 3.1.1.0.0-77 ***----> HANGS HERE FOREVER***
15:30:30 Build was aborted
```

I then added -X to maven command and then I found it hangs at **this command**:

```
 /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin/java -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/local/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/usr/local/apache-maven-2.2.1 -classpath /usr/local/apache-maven-2.2.1/boot/classworlds-1.1.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Durl=http://mavenrepo:8081/nexus/content/repositories/idc-releases -DrepositoryId=mvnp01.repo.com deploy:deploy-file -DuniqueVersion=false -DgroupId=com.mycompany.impaxdatacenter -Dversion=3.1.1.0.0-77_testing_ken2 -DartifactId=$1 -DgeneratePOM=false -Dfile=..//$2 -Dpackaging=$3 -B -X
```

This is also equivalent to this maven deploy:deploy-file command:

```
 mvn -X deploy:deploy-file  org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Durl=http://mavenrepo:8081/nexus/content/repositories/idc-releases -DrepositoryId=mvnp01.repo.com deploy:deploy-file -DuniqueVersion=false -DgroupId=com.mycompany.impaxdatacenter -Dversion=3.1.1.0.0-77_testing_ken2 -DartifactId=$1 -DgeneratePOM=false -Dfile=$2 -Dpackaging=$3 -B
```

**artifactId**   - $1
**path to file** - $2
**package type** - $3

I played around with this command and found that maven hangs forever when uploading a **SECOND** package with **SAME artifactId**.

Is this a bug in maven-deploy-plugin:2.4 ??

Comment: This is fixed by restarting the nexus services.

Comment: Really using Maven 2 ?